# Is there a difference between a sunroof and a moonroof?

Tags: terminology, sunroof

The [sunroof](/questions/tagged/sunroof) tag here states:

> The opening in the roof of a car. Usually a glass panel that opens by sliding down and back.

However, the [owner's manual](https://www.mazda.ca/globalassets/en/pdf/manuals/mazda6/2006mazda6_ownersmanual_en.pdf) of my 2006 Mazda 6 refers to the opening only as a moonroof, and never mentions a sunroof. I've never heard the term moonroof before. To the best of my knowledge, everyone here in Australia refers to it as a sunroof. Are they synonyms, or is there some difference?

For what it's worth, the opening in my Mazda is electronic, and both slides and tilts.

Is there a difference between a sunroof and a moonroof?

Comment: Great question. When I was a kid I always assumed a moonroof was darker (what I would eventually learn to be called 'tinted') and a sunroof was not.

Comment: Moonroofs are sunroofs, but sunroofs aren't moonroofs. Moonroofs have the sliding/tilting mechanisms while sunroofs are either enclosed or will come out like t-tops. The term is pretty much interchangable since you don't see sunroofs anymore really and people just call moonroofs sunroofs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After a little digging, I have found pretty much what Ben said in the comments above: A moonroof is a sunroof, but a sunroof is not a moonroof.

The difference is not in how the mechanism moves, but what it holds. A sunroof consists of a metal panel that can either tilt up, and/or slide back into or above the roof of the car. A moonroof, on the other hand, consists of a glass panel with the same movement functions, The difference being that a moonroof can be closed while still permitting light to come through.

I *assume* they were named this way because a sunroof was a logical name for the device when it was first invented in  1937 (according to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunroof)). The moonroof, invented in 1973 ('37 and '73 - coincidence!?!?), was named as a play on the word 'sun'roof.

Comment: Moonroof, that's just silly.

Comment: The glass is usually tinted, so it can shade you from weak moonlight, but not from harsh sunlight. Moonroof it is.

Comment: I don't recall moonlight ever blinding me so badly that it needs shading. Or cooking my forehead.

Comment: I always just figured they were brand names.

Answer (score 4):

In UK usage, an opening glass panel over the front seats is a sunroof whether it tilts, slides or both.  A second such opening over the *back* seats was sometimes called a moonroof (this was common when the Espace first came out, so late 80s).

Comment: This is my understanding of the terms as well (I'm in the UK). I remember the Land Rover Discovery being the first such vehicle that I heard this talked about: http://www.minimodelshop.co.uk/picture/New-RayToys-54683DG/land-rover-discovery-i-diecast-model-car-new-ray-toys-54683dg-b.jpg

Comment: This was my understanding too.  I first encountered a Moonroof in a 1985 Mitsubishi people carrier.

Comment: My Kia Venga has a moonroof that is a single large glass panel covering both front and rear seats.  When opened it slides back over the luggage area.

Comment: @Chenmunka if there's only one, it's a sunroof (to me).

Comment: @Chenmunka - that is a "panoramic sunroof" to me

Comment: Its a moonroof according to the handbook.  I'll go with that.

Comment: @Chenmunka That woudl agree with the OP's use, but not UK habits.